# How to create several boxes in x and y coordinates and know which one was clicked?

Tags: android, layout, grid-layout

Ive got a little difficult questions for me as a beginner.

I want to create an Android Layout: 
My App does calculate how much rows and colums I need of several Textviews. 
These need to be identified and the text in it needs to be renewed out of a database. Also, if the user touches one of the Textvies, it should take him to another Activity, but he needs to know exactly which of these Textviews he has clicked on.

I have tried to use several listviews, but it wasn't possible for me to identifie the created Textviews in it and make something by the identified data, when they are clicked.

New ideas to do it are really appreciated!

Comment: [GridView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html)

Comment: @Sourabh can I also create the gridview afterwards, not defining it in xml?

Comment: You can do that with any View: `GridView gridView = new GridView(this)`, where `this` might be replaced with another way of retrieving Context